# How to check if Type is a nullable system type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a method that takes a type and determines if it's a user defined class or a system class. My code is as follows.
Method:

```
private static bool isNotCustomClass(Type type)
{
    return SystemTypes.Contains(type) || typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

SystemTypes

```
public static List<Type> SystemTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (_systemTypes == null)
        {
            _systemTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes().ToList();
        }
        return _systemTypes;
    }
}
```

This works for types that are not nullable. However, when I get a type such as `int?`, which comes in as  `` {System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]} ``, it returns false since it doesn't find that type in the list. Any ideas on how to check for nulls, or a better way to run this comparison?

Comment: I'm confused by your mixing of "system class" and "nullable".  What is a "System class"?

Comment: Nullable Types are not a "thing" they are all the same Generic Class Nullable<T> so int? is not a type it is just an instance of Nullable<int>

Comment: System class meaning a system type. I'm trying to check if the type is a class that is user defined.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro: `int?` is just an alternative way of writing `Nullable<int>` - both of them are types; neither is an instance of the other. So `typeof(int?)` and `typeof(Nullable<int>)` are both perfectly valid. (And `Nullable<T>` is a struct, not a class. There's a non-generic `Nullable` class that provides convenience methods.)

Comment: Right, they are an int. I understand that. But when I pass `int?` into this method, it returns false and I need it to return true.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro that should, I think, mean that OP could check for that type in his code, no?

Comment: @Carspn: Which user? How would you classify `Memory<T>` for example? Would that depend on whether the type is part of the framework you're using it on, so "yes" on .NET 5.0 and "no" on .NET Core 2.1 for example?

Comment: Hint: you may find `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, it's not that involved. The majority of types that are going to be used are int, string, DateTime, and bool, all of which may be nullable, as well as user defined objects such as `MyObject`. We're using .NET 4.5, and that `SystemTypes` list I'm using has been working until we implemented nullable objects.

Comment: @JonSkeet what I mean is that int? is not a type per se i is just an equivalent of Nullable<int> in which case the actual type is Nullable<T>

Comment: @Carspn: My point is that "System class meaning a system type" really isn't a very clear classification.

Comment: @JonSkeet: What would be a better way to phrase it? I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: You could start by taking a step back and describing what this is used for: why do you need to make a binary classification between "system types" and "non system types"? What are you doing with that information?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro: It's a type as far as the C# language is concerned. For example, from the ECMA standard: "A nullable value type is written `T?`, where `T` is the underlying type. This syntax is shorthand for `System.Nullable<T>`, and the two forms can be used interchangeably." Nothing about one being a type and the other not being. And the "actual type" of `Nullable<int>` is `Nullable<int>`... `Nullable<T>` is the generic type definition, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @Carspn: If you mean "types defined in the mscorlib assembly" then that's the simplest way of expressing that. I'd also suggest that unless you really *need* the `SystemTypes` list, just checking whether the type's assembly is equal to (say) `typeof(string).Assembly` is probably a simpler way of achieving it. Use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` to find the underlying type for nullable value types, and check whether that underlying type is a system type under your definition.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not agree with you on this one... The type is Nullable<T> and Nullable<int> is not the actual type... As a matter of fact there is a method in the Type class for GetGenericArguments and IsGenericType as well..

Comment: @JonSkeet: That makes a lot more sense, I'll definitely try that out as it seems a lot more intuitive. Thanks for your patience and explaining it in detail, I appreciate it.

Comment: @RickDavin This code is dealing with types. Not instances. So your comment probably doesn't apply.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro The correct way of saying it is: `Nullable<T>` is the open generic type, and `Nullable<int>` is a closed (or constructed) generic type of that. `int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`, end of story.

Comment: @Charlieface i have never read in any documentation about a "constructed type" or "open generic type". Sounds to me like you just made that up. The correct terminology is that Nullable of T is the generic type and int is the underlying type... at least in the microsoft documentation. And even in the code with methods like GetUnderlyingType, GetGenericTypeDefinition or IsGenericType..... So I am not sure what you are talking about,

Comment: By the way a "constructed" type sounds to me more like an instance which is a type that has already executed a constructor.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Please give others on [so] the benefit of the doubt, be prepared to learn from anyone and don't always believe you know everything. In [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) which is the specification for .NET and the CLR, section II.9, it says: "`List``1<T>` is a generic type; it is sometimes termed a generic type, or open generic type because it has at least one generic parameter.  This partition will use the term open type. `List``1<int>` is a closed generic type because it has no unbound generic parameters. ....

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro  ....  (It is sometimes called an instantiated generic type or a generic type instantiation).  This partition will use the term closed type" You will also find [ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf), which defines the C# spec, in section 9.4, talking about constructed types. I admit this last concept is slightly more nuanced: *constructed* means that it has been given type arguments, but we still consider it an *open type* if the arguments themselves are open. Yes, `Nullable<T>` uses the ....

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro ... terminology *underlying type* when referring to it's type parameter (see ECMA-334 9.3.11) but when talking about generic types in general, that is not the term used. Note that ECMA-335 does not use this term

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro: I would *definitely* suggest doing a search before accusing users of making up terminology. Searches for "open generic type" and "constructed type" make it fairly obvious that this is normal terminology. As the convenor of the ECMA C# technical group responsible for C# standardisation, I can confirm pretty categorically that this is indeed correct terminology.

Comment: I stand corrected. I will read the entire ECMA Spec

Comment: @JonSkeet I was wondering whether to ping you to back me up, but I thought it a bit presumptious. I did think it was a rather unkind for JA to jump straight to "you're making this up", I've read ECMA-335 in detail (334 not quite so much), so I thought I had it right. I hope you agree with what I've said above.

Comment: @Charlieface: Yup, it all looks correct to me. (I would suggest we leave the thread there though.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can check if the namespace starts with `System` and get the underlying type in case of `nullable`.

```
public static bool IsSystemType(Type type)
{
    var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if(nullableType != null)
        type = nullableType;
    return type.Namespace.StartsWith("System");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I get a type such as `int?`, which comes in as `` {System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]} ``, it returns false since it doesn't find that type in the list.

You could test all concrete generic types for whether their type definition is `` Nullable`1 ``, then look for its generic type parameter instead:

```
private static bool isNotCustomClass(Type type)
{
    if(type.IsGenericType && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        // Nullable<T> detected, test T instead
        type = type.GenericTypeArguments[0]
    }

    return SystemTypes.Contains(type);
}
```